# Deduping Many-to-Many SQL IDs

Tags: sql, many-to-many, teradata

I have three tables:

```
Email          | EmailID
jack@gmail.com | 100
nate@gmail.com | 101
rex@gmail.com  | 102
```

2nd

```
Email          | CustomerID
jack@gmail.com | 90001
jack@gmail.com | 90002
nate@gmail.com | 90003
rex@gmail.com  | 90003
```

3rd

```
CustomerID  | Purchases
90001       | 1
90002       | 2
90003       | 5
```

As you can see, Jack has 2 customer IDs associated with him, and Customer ID 90003 has two emails associated with it. I want to correctly dedupe customers and give Jack 1 email address and 1 Customer ID (it doesn't matter which one).

So, ideally, I would get the following when summing purchases:

```
Email          | EmailID |CustomerID   | Purchases
jack@gmail.com |  100    |90001        | 3    
nate@gmail.com |  101    |90003        | 5
nate@gmail.com |  102    |90003        | 5
```

Comment: What RDBMS do you use?

Comment: I use Teradata, if that helps

Comment: You should put a constraint on your 2nd (Customer?) table to prevent the same email from having multiple CustomerIDs. Optionally make Email your primary key.

Comment: I can't edit the database, only pull data.

Answer (score 0):

Im so confused though. to get the result you asked for would be something like this.

```
select 
    table1.email,
    table1.emailID,
    min(table2.customerid),
    sum(table3.purchases)
from 
table1 
inner join table2 on table1.email=table2.email
inner join table3 on table2.customerID=table3.customerid
group by
    table1.email,
    table1.emailID,
    table2.email
```

Comment: Sorry, I've edited to give a better example. I need the Email IDs from the first table!

Comment: hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, assuming a typo in your results

To initialize:

```
create table #table1 (email varchar(100), emailid int)
insert into #table1 values ('jack@gmail.com', 100), ('nate@gmail.com', 101), ('rex@gmail.com',102)
create table #table2 (email varchar(100), customerid int)
insert into #table2 values ('jack@gmail.com', 90001), ('jack@gmail.com', 90002), ('nate@gmail.com',90003), ('rex@gmail.com',90003)
create table #table3 (customerid int, purchases int)
insert into #table3 values (90001, 3), (90002, 5), (90003, 5)
```

the query

```
select T1.email,
       (select max(emailid) from #table1 where email = T1.email) as 'emailid',
       (select max(customerid) from #table2 where email = T1.email) as 'customerid',
       (sum(T3.purchases)) as 'purchases' 

from #table1 T1
right join #table2 T2
on T1.email = T2.email
right join #table3 T3
on T2.customerid = T3.customerid
group by T1.email
```